Maximize differential entropy of probability distribution without fixing second moment
(Crossposted from Mathematics Stackexchange)
In Christopher Bishop's book "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning", pages 53-54 specifically, he uses Lagrange multipliers to find the probability distribution $p$ to maximize the differential entropy
$$- \int p(x) \ln{p(x)} dx$$
using the constraints
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) dx = 1$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x p(x) dx = \mu$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x - \mu)^2 p(x) dx = \sigma^2$$
to ensure that $p$ is a probability distribution and to constrain its first and second moments.
After some steps, he arrives at the following equation using the calculus of variations:
$$p(x) = \exp[-1 + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2x + \lambda_3(x-\mu)^2]$$
As I am not too familiar with the calculus of variations, I assume that the $-1$ in the exponent is obtained from the equation itself, the $\lambda_1$ is obtained from the first constraint, the $\lambda_2x$ is obtained from the second constraint, and the $\lambda_3(x-\mu)^2$ is obtained from the third constraint.
By substituting this value of $p$ into the constraint equations to calculate the values of the Lagrange multipliers, he concludes that to maximize differential entropy, $p(x)$ must be the Gaussian distribution.
As I don't fully understand why the first two moments were constrained, I wanted to see what answer I would arrive at if I did not use all three constraints, and to ensure my answer would converge to a non-zero value, I changed the limits of the integrals from $-\infty$ and $\infty$ to $a$ and $b$.
Using only the first constraint, it is easy to see that we arrive at
$$p(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}$$
which is the uniform distribution.
However, I am unable to find what $p$ should be when using the first and second constraints. I am able to calculate the value of $\lambda_1$ as such,
$$\lambda_1 = 1 - \ln[(b-\mu)e^{\lambda_2b} - (a-\mu)e^{\lambda_2a}]$$
$$\lambda_1 = 1 + \ln(\lambda_2) - \ln[e^{\lambda_2b} - e^{\lambda_2a}]$$
but when I try to calculate the value of $\lambda_2$ by equating the right sides of both equations, I end up arriving at the conclusion that $a = b$, which is clearly impossible. What are the correct values of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ and what is the probability distribution $p$ that we arrive at when using the first two constraints?

Regarding the first moment, the solution is translation invariant. Fixing it simply removes that degree of freedom. The second moment in turn needs to be fixed, otherwise the solution wants to "spread out" infinitely, i.e. there is no maximum. If you do not ask about the real line, but about a finite interval, neither is necessary. But to be honest, the way your question is written now, I have no idea what precisely you are asking about. Also it feels more like an MSE than an MO-question.

I want to know the probability distribution I'd arrive at if I didn't fix the second moment, since I'm not able to calculate it myself.
